# (Recursive?) Regex to remove empty xml tags

Tags: regex, xml, recursion, tags, magic-unipaas

I'd like to remove all empty tags from an xml file. However, my options are very limited, so I'd like to use a regex (which is available and known internally here).

I have no problem with the regex to remove the empty tags in their variations, but the nested empty tags are a bit harder, as my regex will only go one deep.

I believe it's because of the named capture group in my recursion, but I'm not able to fix it.

This is what I have so far: [here](https://regex101.com/r/bG6qV4/1)

Best regards and thanks,

Laurent

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: We use magic Unipaas, so it would have to be in the form of a script or dll, without having to install anything extra. We use Windows and windows servers.

Comment: regex shouldn't be used on XML as it is a known format and there are XML parsers out there

Comment: Just because you're familiar with a tool doesn't make it the right tool for the job. In this case it is absolutely the wrong tool for the job. This is what XSLT is for.

Comment: It's not about being familiar with a tool. Our entire package is made with that language. We can't just introduce a different language mid-application for one function.

Comment: Magic-unipaas has no XML parsing libraries, one follower on Stack Overflow, and your "*entire package is made with that language*"?   Sorry, but yours is not a regex problem.

Comment: A few things: 1) I don't see what my number of followers has to do with my question. 2) It's not 'my' package, it's from the company I work for. It's been working smoothly for over 20 years for what we are doing (database intensive operations and consulting), this is just a little extra I'm working on. 3) Completely beside the point. It's not a constructive or helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<root>" +
                    "<tag1>Good</tag1>" +
                    "<tag2 element=\"Good\"></tag2>" +
                    "<tag3 element=\"Good\" />" +
                    "<tag4></tag4>" +
                    "<tag13>" +
                    "</tag13>" +
                    "<tag5 />" +
                    "<tag6/>" +
                    "<tag7>" +
                        "<tag7.1>good</tag7.1>" +
                    "</tag7>" +
                    "<tag8>" +
                        "<tag8.1></tag8.1>" +
                    "</tag8>" +
                    "<tag9>" +
                        "<tag9.1 />" +
                    "</tag9>" +
                    "<tag10>" +
                        "<tag10.1/>" +
                    "</tag10>" +
                    "<tag10>" +
                        "<tag10.1>Wel iets</tag10.1>" +
                    "</tag10>" +
                    "<tag11>" +
                        "<tag11.1 element=\"Good\"/>" +
                    "</tag11>" +
                    "<tag12>" +
                        "<tag12.1></tag12.1>" +
                        "<tag12.2>" +
                            "<tag12.2.1></tag12.2.1>" +
                        "</tag12.2>" +
                    "</tag12>" +
                    "</root>";
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var deleteElements = root.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Descendants().Count() == 0) && (x.Attributes().Count() == 0) && (x.Value.Length == 0)).ToList();
            foreach (XElement deleteElement in deleteElements)
            {
                deleteElement.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```